# Find all links in MySQL that contains a specific string and remove it from all

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to remove the "**http://www.mydomain.com/?**" from my links in my database, where it is found.
Is there any easy way to do it automatically ?

My links are on table wp_postmeta. The meta_key is called _tdomf_custom_permalink and the links are in meta_value.
As i said, the links have this structure http://www.mydomain.com/?http://www.anotherdomain.com/ and the http://www.mydomain.com/? must be removed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta set _tdomf_custom_permalink = replace(_tdomf_custom_permalink, 'http://www.mydomain.com/?', '') WHERE _tdomf_custom_permalink like 'http://www.mydomain.com/?%'
```

Comment: Add a WHERE clause and it starts to look decent

Comment: You can go without WHERE clause in this query if subset of data fields containing "http://www.mydomain.com/?" is proportionally big towards to number of all records in wp_postmeta. If small, WHERE would improve query performance, of course. WHERE clause would look like "WHERE _tdomf_custom_permalink like 'http://www.mydomain.com/?%'"

Comment: WHERE would include a double %. The reason for it is to NOT make more CHANGES than required, not so much SEARCHING since it will scan. Changes involve logging, potentially triggers, index update etc

Comment: "The reason for it is to NOT make more CHANGES than required". I agree. This is a good reason to add WHERE. I've edited my query.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  Just wanted to add the documentation for `REPLACE()` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 0):

Hy , that's simple

```
$query = "SELECT links FROM tabe_name";
$result = msqyl_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $replace = str_replace("http://www.mydomain.com/?","",$row['links']);
    $query_replace = mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET link = '$replace' WHERE id = '$id'");
}
```

This code is understandable to you if you are a begginer, because there are ways to do it in a single sql query.